# Edittext is showing only current date, while selecting other dates

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-datepicker

I am trying to open a date picker after click on editext, which i have achieved, But i am facing a problem that everytime i am selecting a date settext() is getting only current date. Not previous dates.

i have achieved opening datepicker.
also in  my required format.
successfully achieved check for 18 year above age

```
etDob.setOnClickListener {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    val year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)


    val dpd = DatePickerDialog(this, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
        val myFormat: String = "MM/dd/yyyy"

        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US)
        val dob = sdf.format(calendar.getTime())
        etDob!!.setText(dob)

        val userAge = GregorianCalendar(year, month, day)

        val minAdultAge = GregorianCalendar()
        minAdultAge.add(Calendar.YEAR, -18)
        if (minAdultAge.before(userAge)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "18 year", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }, year, month, day)
    dpd.datePicker.maxDate = Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis
    dpd.show()
```

etDob is my edittext where i am opening and setting the age of user
but every time i am selecting a value i am getting current date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set your calendar on Date Set

```
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
```

So your code should be like-

```
val dpd = DatePickerDialog(this, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->

calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
val myFormat: String = "MM/dd/yyyy"

val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US)
val dob = sdf.format(calendar.getTime())
}
```